# Href not visible in scrapy result but visible in html

Tags: python, scrapy, attributes

**Set-up**

I have the next-page button element from [this page](https://www.njuskalo.hr/prodaja-kuca),

```
<li class="Pagination-item Pagination-item--next  Pagination-item--nextSolo ">
                        <button type="button" class="Pagination-link js-veza-stranica kist-FauxAnchor" data-page="2" data-href="https://www.njuskalo.hr/prodaja-kuca?page=2" role="link">Sljedeća&nbsp;<span aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">»</span></button>
                    </li>
```

I need to obtain the url in the `data-href` attribute.

---

**Code**

Using the following simple xpath to the button element in scrapy shell,

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="form_browse_detailed_search"]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/nav/ul/li[8]/button').extract_first()
```

I retrieve,

```
'<button type="button" class="Pagination-link js-veza-stranica" data-page="2">Sljedeća\xa0<span aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">»</span></button>'
```

---

**Question**

Where did the `data-href` attribute go to?

How do I obtain the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-href` attribute is most likely being calculated by some JavaScript code running in your browser. If you look at the raw source code of this page ("view source code" option in your browser), you won't find that attribute there.

The output you see on developer tools is the DOM rendered by your browser, so you can expect differences between your browser view and what Scrapy actually fetches (which is the raw HTML source). Keep in mind that Scrapy doesn't execute any JavaScript code.

Anyway, a way to solve this would be building the pagination URL based on the `data-page` attribute:

```
from w3lib.url import add_or_replace_parameter
...

next_page = response.css('.Pagination-item--nextSolo button::attr(data-page)').get()
next_page_url = add_or_replace_parameter(response.url, 'page', next_page)
```

`w3lib` is an open source library: https://github.com/scrapy/w3lib

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and solution. `w3lib.url` is very neat!